# Principle of the Argument: How do I get the $\Delta{\arg f(z)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

[image: copied from M2PM3 lecture note by Ari Laptev]

I didn't really understand why the multi-valued function, $\log$ was used instead of single-valued function, $\mathrm{Log}$.

Also, could you please explain me how in the examples, the $\Delta{\arg f(z)}$ is $6\pi$, $-2\pi$, and $0$?

I don't understand because the why in 1. and 2. would actually count the total argument changed when $\theta$ is rotating from $0$ to $2\pi$, whereas 3. would just result $0$, not $2\pi$.

It would be great to know how to calculate $\Delta{\arg f(z)}$.

Comment: Ok, if I remember correctly, there are two ways to look at examples 1,2,3. First, recall that we are consider the curve $\gamma$, and the "inside" of the curve. So you could try to imagine traversing $\gamma$ and noticing that in example 1, you make three laps ($6\pi$) around for example $z = 0$ inside of $\gamma$ starting at $\theta = 0$. In example 3, we do no not make a lap around $z = 0$. The other way to look at is to simply use the formula. It implies that for example 3, there are $0$ zeroes and $0$ poles inside $\gamma$, so $\Delta\arg f(z) = 0-0 = 0$.

Comment: @probablyme Hi! Thanks for the comment. I still didn't really understand the example 3, with the first method you explained .So does it mean it has to have a lap around $z=0$ in order to have a $\Delta arg f(z) > 0$?

Comment: In my other comment, I realized I meant $\arg f(z)$ not $z = 0$. I'm not an expert so I might be making a mistake, but remember we are traversing $\gamma$. Notice that $\gamma$ is a path along the unit circle. However, $f(z)$ $(3.)$ takes that unit circle and shifts it. So, as I remember it, as you traverse $\gamma$ and consider $\arg f(z)$, we notice that there is no increase in $\arg f(z)$. So $\Delta \arg f(z) = 0$.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are *forbidden* on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).